# change Product Detail page in magento?

Tags: magento, product

I want  functionality of my product detail page like :
 http://en.edelices.com/foies-gras-truffles/goose-foie-gras/millefeuille-whole-goose-foie-gras-truffles-fresh.html.

I have done other part but. how to add product in different Weight with different image and when select radio button change the image of product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create each product as a [configurable and several simple](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/) products. Each simple product can have it's own price, weight and image. Use an extension to [dynamically switch images](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/temgra/extension/893/color-swatches) between those simple ones.